# Regex Algorythm Named Capture Group problem c#

Tags: c#, regex

Capture Named Group not working as expected.

**Target**

I first search for the specific QR code and then work my way from right to left to find the amount as well as the date of the payment.

**Flags**

- Global
- Multiline
- Right to Left

**Data**

Full Regex C#

```
(?(?!\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2,4}).*\n|(?<Date>.*))*(?(?!CHF\s\d+\.\d+).*\n|(?<Amount>.*))*85 03870 00000 00000 00001 00258
```

Full String

> 20.09.2022 Gutschrift QR-Rechnung 20.09.2022 919.05 39'228.62 Betrag CHF 809.10
> ********* | ******* | 8704 Angaben ohne Gewähr Seite 10 / 39AEK BANK 1826
> ********* · ********** Tel. ************ · www.*****.ch IID/BC-Nr. ******** · PC-Nr. ******** · CHE-******* MWST Kontoauszug Datum Buchungstext Valuta Belastung Gutschrift Saldo CHF Mitteilung /
> Referenz 85 03870 00000 00000 00001 00263
> ************* Entschädigung
> ************* Betrag CHF 109.95 Mitteilung / Referenz 85 03870 00000 00000 00001 00258

Link: https://regex101.com/r/juS3iw/1

**The Issue**

The current Issue is that the pointer is in the wrong place after using `(?(?!CHF\s\d+\.\d+).*\n|(?<Amount>.*))*` or `(?(?!\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2,4}).*\n|(?<Date>.*))*` , so I cannot get the Named Capture Group like I tried in this example. The bottom Description says it does not consume characters, but here it seems that this is not the case.

**Descripiton (?!...)**
Starting at the current position in the expression, ensures that the given pattern will not match. Does not consume characters.

**Expected output**

- Amount: CHF 109.95
- Date: 20.09.2022

Thanks for any help

**Current Solution**

```
(?<Date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}).*?(?<Valuta>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}).*?(?<Currency>CHF|EUR).*?(?<Amount>\d+\'\d+\.\d{2}|\d+\.\d{2})(?:(?!\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2,4}).)*?85 03870 00000 00000 00001 00258
```

Do you think that's a good solution?

https://regex101.com/r/7bXOBg/1

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/juS3iw/2

Comment: [`\b(?<Date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2,4})\b.*(?<Amount>\bCHF\s\d+\.\d+)(?!.*\bCHF\s\d+\.\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/juS3iw/3) should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the first date that you want, you can do it like this

```
(?<=\sCHF\s)(?<Amount>\d+\.\d+)(?!.*\sCHF\s)|^(?<Date>\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})
```

Explanation:

- General form: `select amount|select date` where `|` means OR.
- `(?<=\sCHF\s)` amount must follow `" CHF "`
- `(?<Amount>\d+\.\d+)` named capture group for amount.
- `(?!.*\sCHF\s)` amount must not precede any `whatever + " CHF "`. This ensures that we catch the last amount.
- `^` must start at beginning of string.
- `(?<Date>\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})` named capture group for date.

However, if the date is always at the start of the string, you can get it more efficiently with `string date = qrString.Substring(0, 10);`, or, with a range (.NET Core only): `string date = qrString[..10];`